# React JS не отображается компонент

Tags: babel, reactjs

Почему то когда я пишу просто  ReactDOM.rener и там прописываю теги, к примеру h1, то react  работает,
но через компоненты нет. подключал и jsx компилятор и babel и в type прописывал их

```js
var app = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return ( < h2 > sdfdf < /h2>
    )
  }

});


ReactDOM.render( < app / > , document.getElementById('result'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/6.1.19/browser.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Наименование компонента надо писать с заглавной буквы,
также исправить название компонента в ReactDOM

Comment: исправил, все равно не работает. подключал как и отдельным файлом js так и в index.html.
проверял на codepen, все работает.
все зависимости я подключил, код компоненты с заглавной буквы но не работает вообще, даже alert не работает, когда убираю type="text/babel", alert работает, в консоле пишет что лишняя "<" перед тэгом в компоненте, я даже убирал тэги все равно это же пишет.
jsx transform не нашел, сайт react все через npm делает никакой ссылки для скачивания на глав стрнице
в общем не знаю  в чем прикол уже все перепробовал, в js fiddle тоже работает

Comment: Если ругается на символ скобки "<", то в большинстве случаев он не понимает jsx. Привидите полный пример кода с исправлениями

Answer (score -1):

Проблема была в подключении babel.

```js
  var App = React.createClass({ 
              render: function() { return (
                <h1>Hello World</h1>
              )} 
            }); 
  
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('result') );
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="result"></div>
```

```
https://jsfiddle.net/4sk1deko/
```